# Can integration tests be run asynchronously with Maven?

Tags: integration-tests, maven, cucumber

Because I work at a company with lots and lots of computers, I find it to be a little ironic that it takes half an hour to cut a release of the latest version of our software.

The bottleneck seems to be integration tests run by Maven, and the cause of the bottleneck is because those integration tests seem to want to be run sequentially.  There isn't any real reason for them to be run in order, other than the fact that they're lots of Cucumber tests run against a single database that has to be set up and torn down for every feature.

So, my question is, how do we fail faster with Maven?

Comment: https://opencredo.com/test-automation-concepts-parallel-test-execution/